# My discord bot not responding, how can i fix?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am using "discord.js" and I wrote a slash command it was a test code. But I'm getting the "Application not responding" message. How can I fix?

```
const {SlashCommandBuilder, CommandInteraction, PermissionFlagsBits} = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("ping")
    .setDescription("Pong")
    .setDefaultMemberPermissions(PermissionFlagsBits.Administrator),
    execute(interaction) {
        interaction.reply({content: "Pong", ephemeral: true})
    },
};
```

Comment: Have you registered the command? Also ensure your command handler is properly set

Comment: I just started using discord.js. But I'm sure the command is registered. If you have any other questions, I'd appreciate it if you could explain more. Like I said, I'm ignorant about discord.js.

Comment: Checkout the [Registering Slash Commands](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/command-deployment.html#registering-slash-commands) section on the DJS guide. You'll know you're registering commands when you make a post request to the Discord API

Comment: Have you checked if `execute` runs? Try `console.log`ging something from there.

Comment: I looked at the page you posted and yes, it creates an array and saves the codes in it, and at the end it tells me which codes are saved from the console.

Comment: Make sure your client is logged in as @zmehall suggested. If it is, the problem may lie in your command handler. Try logging `client.commands` (or however you store your commands) and make sure a collection of command data returns